# chatbot app reply always missing a letter of the variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a chatbot using HTML and javascript. I used an open source ELIZA-style code available online as my starting point. However I noticed an issue with the code:

For example the code says:

```
var convpatterns = new Array (
new Array (".*my name is (.*)\.", "Nice to meet you $1!"),                                                          
new Array ("^I (?:wish |would like )(?:I could |I was able to |to be able to )(.*)\.","What would it be like to be able to $1?"));

uinput = ""
soutput = ""
dialog = ""

function mainroutine() {
  uinput = document.mainscreen.BasicTextArea4.value;
  dialog = dialog + "User: " + uinput +  '\r' + "\n";
  conversationpatterns()
  dialog = dialog  +  '\r' + "\n";
  updatescreen()
}

function conversationpatterns() {
  for (i=0; i < convpatterns.length; i++) {                           
    re = new RegExp (convpatterns[i][0], "i");
    if (re.test(uinput)) {
      len = convpatterns[i].length - 1;
      index = Math.ceil( len * Math.random());
      reply = convpatterns[i][index];
      soutput = uinput.replace(re, reply);
      soutput = initialCap(soutput);
      dialog = dialog + "System: " + soutput +  '\r' + "\n";
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

However if I ask the bot "I wish I could fly", the bot will reply "What would it be like to be able to fl"
Noticed the "fly" is missing a "y" letter at the end. It happens everytime no matter what I typed, for example "my name is Michelle", and the bot reply "Nice to meet you Michell", again missing the last letter of the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove last dot in your regexp

```
new Array ("^I (?:wish |would like )(?:I could |I was able to |to be able to )(.*)\.","What would it be like to be able to $1?"))
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^
```

Change to this

```
new Array ("^I (?:wish |would like )(?:I could |I was able to |to be able to )(.*)","What would it be like to be able to $1?"))
```

You can test it here:

https://regex101.com/r/hN2gA2/1